# WCF Service Endpoints not reachable from local

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I am new to WCF development and I am trying to create a WCF service hosted in a console app.

I have already created the WCF service and tested it by running it on IIS Express. Doing so, the WCF service will be accessible from `http://localhost:5576/MyFirstService.svc`. Within the service, I have defined a GET endpoint `/test/<param>` just to test if it works. Upon visiting the url with Postman `http://localhost:5576/MyFirstService.svc/test/123`, it will echo back `123`.

My console app that hosts the WCF on the other hand is super simple. I followed the tutorial (http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2014/05/wcf-self-hosting-console-application.html). The relevant code is below:

```
Uri httpBaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:4321/StudentService");

//Instantiate ServiceHost
studentServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(StudentService.StudentService), httpBaseAddress);

//Add Endpoint to Host
studentServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(StudentService.IStudentService), new WSHttpBinding(), "");            

//Metadata Exchange
ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
serviceBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
studentServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceBehavior);

//Open
studentServiceHost.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Service is live now at : {0}", httpBaseAddress);
Console.ReadKey();
```

As I launched the console app and visited `http://localhost:4321/StudentService`, I am greeted with the standard page talking about wsdl. However, if I tried to visit `http://localhost:4321/StudentService/test/123`, I get a 400 bad request error.

Am I doing things right? What is the path that I should be using to get to my endpoints? I tried many variations of the URL and it just does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your first service, http://localhost:5576/MyFirstService.svc, was running within the context of IIS (yes even though it's express) so that is what allows for the URL (REST style) routing like you were seeing in your "test/123" example.

But the code example, and posted reference link, is actually a self-hosted service from a console application which doesn't utilize IIS or WAS (Windows Activation Service) so routing won't be available.

Don't get me wrong, your StudentService will still work just fine if called via SOAP, just not from a REST perspective which is what Postman is used for.

There are free tools out there like [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) that work just like Postman to test your WCF services.

Comment: So, if I am understanding what you are saying. I currently have 2 options.

(Option 1) Use SoapUI to test calling my console-hosted WCF via SOAP.
(Option 2) Re-deploy my WCF Service in IIS or WAS to allow for RESTful access.

Am I understanding this correctly?